# Simple CEF project not show page

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

Try use CEF from C++. Make simple project:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <include/cef_app.h>
#include <include/cef_client.h>
#include <include/wrapper/cef_helpers.h>

class Handler : public CefClient {
public:

private:
    IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(Handler);
};

class App : public CefApp, public CefBrowserProcessHandler {
public:
    CefRefPtr<CefBrowserProcessHandler> GetBrowserProcessHandler() override {
        return this;
    }

    void OnContextInitialized() override {
        CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

        CefRefPtr<Handler> handler(new Handler);

        CefWindowInfo wndInfo;
        wndInfo.SetAsPopup(0, "Hello world");

        CefBrowserSettings settings;

        std::string url{ "https://stackoverflow.com" };
        CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser(wndInfo, handler, url, settings, nullptr, nullptr);
    }

private:
    IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(App);
};

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    CefEnableHighDPISupport();

    CefMainArgs args(hInstance);
    int ec = CefExecuteProcess(args, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (ec >= 0) {
        return ec;
    }

    CefSettings settings;

    CefRefPtr<App> app(new App);

    CefInitialize(args, settings, app, nullptr);

    CefRunMessageLoop();

    CefShutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

Project folder contains all files from cefclient(official cef example)

```
08.04.2020  12:21         2 133 001 cef.pak
08.04.2020  12:21           654 037 cef_100_percent.pak
08.04.2020  12:21           808 292 cef_200_percent.pak
08.04.2020  12:21         1 772 827 cef_extensions.pak
08.04.2020  12:21         1 110 016 chrome_elf.dll
08.04.2020  12:21         4 346 120 d3dcompiler_47.dll
08.04.2020  12:21         7 015 266 devtools_resources.pak
08.04.2020  12:21        10 505 952 icudtl.dat
08.04.2020  12:21       158 316 032 libcef.dll
08.04.2020  12:21           391 168 libEGL.dll
08.04.2020  12:21        10 552 832 libGLESv2.dll
08.04.2020  12:44    <DIR>          locales
09.04.2020  18:14           613 247 main.obj
09.04.2020  18:14         3 948 032 Project1.exe
08.04.2020  12:21           606 640 snapshot_blob.bin
08.04.2020  12:49    <DIR>          swiftshader
08.04.2020  12:21           923 968 v8_context_snapshot.bin
09.04.2020  18:14           519 168 vc142.idb
09.04.2020  18:14           847 872 vc142.pdb
```

why can i get a blank page?

Comment: Please do not post links to external sites. Just post the text inside your question. I edited your question and copied the text from pastebin, please revise my edit if needed.

Comment: have you tried to use qt

Comment: Thanks! I don't need a dependency on Qt

Comment: I'd like to know if you have a prev experience with it to help me to decide which one of them (chromium/qt) I should use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Add manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">

  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

</assembly>
```

Comment: Please tell me, what is this manifest file? Why did everything work after adding it ? Where is it written about him ?